Prove that $T$ is a complete statistic and find a UMVUE for $p$
While preparing for my prelims, I came across this problem:
Let $X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n$ be a sequence of Bernoulli trials, $n \geq 4.$ It is given that, $X_1,X_2,X_3 \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} Ber(\frac12),$ and for $4\leq i \leq n,$ $P(X_i=X_{i-1}|X_1,\cdots,X_{i-1})=1-p,$ $p \in (0,1).$ Consider $T:=\sum_{i=4}^n |X_i-X_{i-1}|$. Is $T$ complete? Hence (or otherwise), find a UMVUE for $p$.
All I have been able to show so far is that $S:=\frac{T}{n-3}$ is unbiased for $p$. If I can show further that $T$ is complete sufficient for $p$, $S$ will be a UMVUE, by Lehmann-Scheffe. How do I prove that $T$ is complete? I failed at finding a neat expression for $E[f(T)],$ where $f$ is Borel measurable.

Here's an elegant solution (provided by a senior Ph.D. candidate):
Let $Z_i=|X_i-X_{i-1}|,$ $4\leq i \leq n.$ Then, easy to show that $Z_i \sim Ber(p)$. Further, for $4\leq i < j \leq n$:
$$E[Z_i Z_j]=E[E[Z_iZ_j|X_1,\cdots,X_{i}]]=E[Z_iE[Z_j|X_1,\cdots,X_i]]=E[Z_iE[E[Z_j|X_1,...,X_{j-1}]|X_1,\cdots,X_i]]=E[Z_i p]=p^2=E[Z_i]E[Z_j].$$
Hence, $Z_i, Z_j$ are uncorrelated, or equivalently, independent. Finally $T \sim Bin(n-3,p),$ and hence is complete sufficient for $p.$

This is a reminder to all users that comments are for discussing questions and answers. The Code of Conduct and Be Nice policy apply everywhere on the site, including comments. More information is in the [help].

You write "Hence, $Z_i, Z_j$ are uncorrelated, or equivalently, independent." A previous comment pointed out that "uncorrelated" and "independent" are not equivalent concepts. Without further development for why $Z_i, Z_j$ are independent, this is not a valid answer to the question. You can improve the answer with an [edit].

Conflating uncorrelated and independent should result in getting the question wrong at any level, regardless of whether or not you feel that being explicit about your reasoning is "spoon-feeding." You should [edit] to include the crucial information to your answer.

@Wrik Since establishing independence is a crucial step here, please add the details in your answer that you mention in your comment.

This site is not intended to be a Q&A site limited to people who have reached the level of "graduate or advanced undergraduate" students.   There are many people who struggle with basic concepts or sometimes misunderstandings of more advanced concepts, and replying to their questions with answers that they aren't likely to be able to follow isn't helpful.   For example, many people can read your question and see fairly quickly that $T \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n-3,p)$, but won't see why that means that $T$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $p$....

In effect, you've done the easiest part of the proof by stating "easy to show that..." and then stated that the hard part is obvious and you won't spoon-feed the readers by detailing it.   Again, not helpful.  There is no proof there.

This is the site where the proofs are supposed to be!  If a reader has to resort to Google to find a proof to a statement in an answer, the answer has probably not done its job.

You might also want to ask yourself what the purpose of Cross-Validated, or indeed all of StackExchange, is, if "Go look it up on the Internet" is considered an acceptable answer to a question posted here.
